# Voltage drop out of nowhere

Tags: voltage, batteries, led-strip, esp8266

I have this weird issue. I'm currently hooking up a 6-pack of 18650 batteries in parallel. I'm currently hitting 3.8v using the whole pack at the connector (yes, I need to charge them up). If I hook up my 5 meters of LED strip to it, I get a voltage drop in the beginning, which is really weird! Here's how I've hooked it up:

[image]

The VIN on the ESP8266 board can receive a wide range of voltage, so it doesn't matter if it gets 3.3v or 5v. The batteries won't ever go below 3.5v, so I don't need to worry about that.

The VIN pin receives about 1.3v whereas the first LED receives the 3.8v. The terminal/connector that splits the cables is simply [one of these connectors](http://www.usledsupply.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/o/power_connector_male_screw.gif). So the battery pack has a male connector, that connects to the female, which simply has two cables running from it.

What on earth is wrong?

Comment: Mixed up the blue wire with the black one? What if you disconnect the LEDS?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Nope they're not mixed up and the LED strip turns on. It's like the ESP8266 board doesn't run the actual device, because the LEDs are white (they are so until it connects to my WiFi), but the usual LED that indicates that the board is on is not on. So it's like it's running some of the code, but it's not running the WiFi things (makes sense since it's only 1.3v). Oh and it works fine if I disconnect the LED strip.

Comment: What if you remove the blue wire?

Comment: Can you put the red wire to the ESP directly to the battery? Do the same with the black wire (one at a time) and see if that helps.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The LED strip remembers the state (they have a small chip) and therefore still doesn't work (just tried).

Comment: @RonBeyer If I remove the strip completely, the ESP8266 turns on like it should.

Comment: @MortenMoulder I am asking what is happening with the voltage drop, not about "works".

Comment: Are the wires thick enough to handle the current?

Comment: I'm not saying remove the strip, I'm saying bypass the connector/splitter and go directly to the battery, leave the LED hooked up as well.

Comment: @RonBeyer It stays the exact same.

Comment: @peufeu Definitely. I can barely fit the copper through the ESP8266 holes.

Comment: @RonBeyer But the battery is hooked up directly to the ESP8266.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the contraption?

Comment: @peufeu https://imgur.com/a/J965j - The battery pack hooks up to the female connector. Ignore the bad solders, I'm trying all kind of things at the moment and will do better. I have not hooked up 5 meters at the moment, so I'm just using probably 30 LEDs total at the moment. The "finished product" will include more wires for the strip, to account for the voltage drop at the bottom.

Comment: Damn, everything looks fine. This is one of these voodoo failures...

Comment: @peufeu I know, right? The connector reads the 3.8v but the VIN and GND on the ESP8266 reads the 1.3v. I wish I could take a picture, but I don't have 6 hands :(

Comment: How do you measure?

Comment: Oh hey, I forgot to mention this: If I remove the battery pack and replace the plug with a 5V 4A supply, it reads 5v at the ESP8266. No voltage drop. If that helps anything.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Multimeter. Red to VIN and black to GND.

Comment: Dunno.. start making holes in the wire and measure voltage on different lengths until you find where it goes... I suspect a bad contact at some point.

Comment: Maybe the strands are broken in the wire? Maybe your multimeter's battery is flat?

Comment: Huh, this is extremely weird. I cut myself some new red wire and soldered it to the board and now it works. I have NO clue why. I did resolder the red wire a few times in between. Looks like a faulty cable maybe? Well damn.

Comment: Post an answer so the question doesn't sit in limbo. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: Bad wire... not uncommon. It happens.

Comment: You can dissect the wire for forensics! Maybe the strands are broken inside, or something went wrong during fabrication...

Comment: @peufeu I tossed that crap out already haha. I didn't want to risk using it in another project :-P But yeah, it was probably because of the strands!

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it was a bad wire. I resoldered the original one probably 5 times total, but decided to grab a new wire and then it worked perfectly.

As peufeu said in one of the comments: *This is one of these voodoo failures*

Comment: Actually it's one of those... "If I tried all the possible problems and found nothing, then I need to check the impossible problems." problems.

Comment: @Trevor Haha that's true!

Comment: Ha this happens to me always !